# Copy Image to Clipboard from Bash

Tags: command-line, clipboard

Suppose I have an image on the desktop,

```
$ ls
1.png
```

I'd like to copy it to the clipboard,and tried

```
$ pbcopy 1.png

^C
```

I should terminate the process manually.

How to copy image to clipboard, so I can paste them around?

Answer (score 2):

From `man pbcopy`:

```
pbcopy  takes  the standard input and places it in the specified paste-
board.
```

It doesn't take a filename as an argument, but uses standard input. So:

```
pbcopy < 1.png
```